# Buscando e alterando o valor das checkbox com javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando buscar e alterar os valores de uma checkbox usando Javascript. A intenção é, quando a função JS for chamada, verificar se a checkbox está setada. Caso não, sete-a como checada, e vice versa. Porém ao tentar ler o estado da checkbox é mostrado o seguinte erro:"Cannot read property 'checked' of null"

A minha última tentativa até agora foi o seguinte:

```
<label for="letrasMinusculas">
<img src="images/checked.png" id="imgLetrasMinusculas" onclick="changeIcon(letrasMinusculas)">
</label>

<input id="letrasMinusculas" class="boxOculto" name="letrasMinusculas" type="checkbox" checked>
```

E no Javascript:

```
function changeIcon(id){
                           var status = document.getElementById(id);
                           if (status.checked){
                            alert("Verdadeiro");
                           }
                           else{alert("Falso");}
                    }
```

Obs: A checkbox recebe a classe "boxOculto" (display: none) pois preferi usar um label com imagem para o usuário clicar por questões de personalização.

Comment: Tentou passar a ID como string? assim `onclick="changeIcon('letrasMinusculas')"` ?

Comment: Era esse mesmo o erro. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Sua função esta funcionando corretamente, o que você esta passando como parametro id ? tem que ser `'letrasMinusculas'`, no seu else você pode setar `checked = true` se é isto mesmo que você precisa.

**Exemplo:**

```js
function changeIcon(id) {
  var status = document.getElementById(id);
  if (status.checked) {
    alert("Verdadeiro");
  } else {
    alert("Falso");
    status.checked = true;
  }
}

changeIcon('letrasMinusculas');
```

```html
<input id="letrasMinusculas" class="boxOculto" name="letrasMinusculas" type="checkbox" checked>
```

Comment: Cara, exatamente isso. Deu certinho aqui. Valeu mesmo.
Só não precisei setar como "true" pois como a minha imagem já é um label para a checkbox, basta eu clicar sobre ela que a mesma seta automático.

Mas valeu mesmo pelo help.

Comment: @MatheusGodoi Que bom que funcionou!